# Is this SSH config misconfigured and a security risk?

Tags: ssh, security

**EDIT:** See answer below, my assumptions were incorrect.

If I have the following in my SSH config (`~/.ssh/config` on OS X), is this a security risk?

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-secret-key.pem
```

My understanding is that I would be sending my secret key to any host I `ssh` into. Is this correct? If yes, is this a security risk? Could the host in theory try to use my secret key to log into some major SSH hosts (like GitHub)?

If I specify `HostName`, am I correct in thinking that the key is only sent to that host:

```
Host *
  HostName github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-secret-key.pem
```

The [official docs for setting up SSH for GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) seem to suggest to use the first config...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH does *not* send your private keys to the server. The mechanism is based on calculation using what the entity possesses - the server computes something based on the public key, the client based on the private key (see [this Information Security Stack Exchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/23227/54387) for more).

In any case, whether you add the keys to the agent or not, SSH tries all keys until one succeeds. Unless you have Agent Forwarding setup, I don't think there's anyway for anything on the *server* to be able to use the keys added to the agent.

---

```
Host *
  HostName github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

This sets the `Hostname` of every `Host` to `github.com`, which is most certainly not something you want to do (this means `ssh foo.bar` will connect to `github.com`). If you want to apply some configuration to only connections to `github.com`, use that as the `Host` pattern:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-secret-key.pem
```

---

Whether it's a security risk depends on who you're defending against. If your SSH keys are password-protected, and someone else is capable of accessing the SSH agent on your system, sure, this opens up all the password-protected keys to access once they are added to the agent.

But I'd say that threat is unlikely.